# Match specific numbers and before after have or regex escaped

Tags: regex

With /\escape/ I can escape special regex right? But why isn't working?
I'm trying to search specific numbers from the beginning which start with `|something` in the middle have numbers only `[0-9]` and ends with `|` again.
Also have other string etc from left and from the right like so `left|something[0-9]|right`

This is what I've done, but is not working

```
/\|/234123[0-9]/\|/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` only escapes the next character, so the second forward slash is ending the regular expression. Instead, you want this:

`/\|something[0-9]\|/`

You have to make sure that `something` is escaped correctly.

Note that if you need to match any number not just a digit, you need `[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 0):

What would probably help you the most would be the right tool for the job:

https://regex101.com/r/ZdjhCE/2

You'll still have to set your language, as regex are similar between languages, but unluckily not 100% identical.